# Covariance stationarity - Example

Tags: time-series, self-study, stationarity

I am studying time series by myself.

I've just faced this process: $y_t = \epsilon_t \epsilon_{t-1}$, where $\epsilon_t$ is Gaussian white noise, with zero mean and variance equal to one.

Is this an example of covariance stationarity?

Comment: Welcome to CV, mark teck!